# 404 error when deploying Scrapy

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, deployment, scrapy

I am trying to deploy `Django+Scrapy` project on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run `scrapyd-deploy`, as it is described in the [docs](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client#scrapyd-deploy), - I get:

```
Packing version 1526639948
Deploying to project "first_scrapy" in http://my_ip/addversion.json
Deploy failed (404): <full HTML code of '404.html' page>
```

When I run `scrapyd-deploy -l` - I see:

```
default              http://my_ip
```

My `scrapy.cfg`:

```
[settings]
default = first_scrapy.settings

[deploy]
url = http://my_ip
username = root
password = rootpassword
project = first_scrapy
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**
If I change in my `scrapy.cfg` `url=http://my_ip:6800` - this still throws `404 error`. Next I tried to run `scrapyd` in the second console and this was the first time I saw another answer - details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453479/valueerror-while-deploying-scrapy).
So question now is - how to run `scrapyd` constantly so if I close the console - it will be still working?

Comment: is scrapyd running at `http://my_ip` and is accessible to public ?

Comment: @Umair how can I check that?

Comment: Lol, just open yourServer:6800 in your browser

Comment: @Umair I thought there might be some another "cleverer" way :) If I remember correctly (I am not at the comp now) :6800 is disabled now, to get access to it I have to run `scrapyd` - there appears a console and after that I can see scrapyd page, but I still can't run `scrapyd-deploy` successfully. And access disappears after I close a console.

Comment: When scrapyd server is on and you try to deploy, what error do you see then?

Comment: @Umair there is still the same 404 error.

Comment: `Deploying to project "first_scrapy" in http://my_ip/addversion.json`

isnt scrapyd running on `http://my_ip:6800` instead of `http://my_ip/`

Comment: `url = http://my_ip` should be `url = http://my_ip:6800`

Comment: @Umair if I remember correctly I tested that and that didn't help. But I will play with that later once again, when I come to my comp. I will let you know if that helps, thank you.

Comment: Ok. Btw, if the server where scrapyd is running and the server you are trying to deploy from are different then make sure scrapyd is accessible via browser to public

Comment: @Umair that helped a bit - answer changed, i saw `200 response`, but got another error (probably not connected with Scrapy) - I have posted another question about that. But here I have one more question - can you see please my update?

Comment: Please read my answer below. It answers the new question you have asked too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change directory into your project folder and then run scrapyd command with “nohup” and that will make sure that scrapyd doesn’t get closed after you disconnect with server

```
cd /path/to/your/project && nohup scrapyd >& /dev/null &
```

Comment: looks like that might be working -  I still see `my_ip:6800` if I close the console. Are there any cases when I should do something more with `scrapyd`? To restart it or anything else? How can I do that in similar way? Or may be where can I read more info? P.S. I will try to deal with that second error - and if scrapy will be working - I accept your answer.

Comment: Do something more with scrapyd? Means?

Comment: Only way to restart it first you should kill its process and then run the above command again

Comment: one more question - how can I check if `scrapyd` is currently running or not, without accessing it in url?

Comment: or do `curl localhost:6800`

Comment: yep, thank you, first didn't work, second worked. And also I have found another way - `netstat -lntu`.

Comment: Ooops sorry, its `ps -aux | grep scrapyd`