# ValueError while deploying Scrapy

Tags: python, django, debugging, deployment, scrapy

I am trying to deploy Scrapy with `scrapyd-deploy` command and now it throws next error:

```
    Packing version 1526919848
    Deploying to project "first_scrapy" in http://my_ip:6800/addversion.json
    Server response (200):
    {"node_name": "polo", "message": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py\", line 558, in configure\n    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])\n
      File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py\", line 731, in configure_handler\n    result = factory(**kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py\", line 1008, in __init__\n    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())\n
      File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py\", line 1037, in _open\n    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)\nNotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/first_scrapy-1526919848-13w8cqlm.egg/debug.log'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\n
    Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py\", line 184, in _run_module_as_main\n    \"__main__\", mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n
      File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 40, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 37, in main\n    execute()\n  File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py\", line 109, in execute\n    settings = get_project_settings()\n
      File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py\", line 68, in get_project_settings\n    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')\n  File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py\", line 292, in setmodule\n    module = import_module(module)\n
      File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py\", line 126, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n
      File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _gcd_import\n
  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 969, in _find_and_load\n
  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n
  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 664, in _load_unlocked\n
  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible\n
      File \"/tmp/first_scrapy-1526919848-13w8cqlm.egg/first_scrapy/settings.py\", line 25, in <module>\n  File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py\", line 22, in setup\n    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\n
      File \"/home/chiefir/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/log.py\", line 75, in configure_logging\n    logging_config_func(logging_settings)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py\", line 795, in dictConfig\n    dictConfigClass(config).configure()\n
      File \"/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py\", line 566, in configure\n    '%r: %s' % (name, e))\n

    ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/first_scrapy-1526919848-13w8cqlm.egg/debug.log'\n", 

    "status": "error"}
```

Line 24 and 25 in first_scrapy.settings are:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

And here is `my_project.settings.LOGGING`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
        },
        'mail_admins': {
              'level': 'ERROR',
              'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

And `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`
As I unserstand something is wrong in `settings.LOGGING` but I can't get what. Can you help me?
This is not duplicate. That is the similar question, but I have different reasons of this error - I don't create.I have checked everything as it is shown on that question - and it works on local sever.

Comment: are you really working in `/tmp/first_scrapy-1526919848-13w8cqlm.egg` folder as shows the `BASE_DIR` ?

Comment: @Evhz, no, that is some `magic` dirrectory, created by `Scrapy` authomatically, as I understand.

Comment: ok, then it seems BASE_DIR is overriden by Scrapy. Try to use, just for now, a static folder for debug.log. Something like `/tmp/debug.log` and check if the app can start, and log there.

Comment: @abdul_niyas_pm that is the similar question, but that I have different reasons of that. Delete please your duplicate label. I have checked everything as it is shown on that question - and it works on local sever.

Comment: @Evhz yep, that helped, error disappeared. How can I fix that in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `BASE_DIR` is declared and used from scrapy side, everything you set inside that settings file in the form of:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

would make reference to the path where scrapy works, shown in the error as:

```
/tmp/first_scrapy-1526919848-13w8cqlm.egg
```

So better define your own `LOG_DIR` in the settings file, not using the current path, in a know folder you can use:

```
LOG_DIR = '/path/to/logs/'

'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'debug.log')
```

Or, set an environment variable in other file of your project (maybe in django) easily to grab from settings file:

Any other `.py` file:

```
import os
os.environ['LOG_DIR'] = '/path/to/log/'
```

In `settings.py` file:

```
LOG_DIR=os.environ['LOG_DIR']

'filename': os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'debug.log')
```

**Also** you could log to `/tmp` using the relative path, as follows:

```
'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'debug.log')
```